# Rails - How to connect Helper to Controller Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have helper:

```
module BreadcrumbsHelper
  def breadcrumbs_cache_wrap(key, options, &block)
    ...
  end
end
```

And i extract part of Controller to module:

```
module ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs

  def default_breadcrumbs
  ...
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs

  ...
end
```

Now i want to connect Helper to Controller. I can do it like this:

```
class ApplicationController
  include ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs
  helper :breadcrumbs

  ...
end
```

It's working. **The question is how to incapsulate connection to Breadcrumbs Module?**

```
module ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs     
  helper :breadcrumbs

  ...
end
```

Unfortunately this code is not working "undefined method `helper'".

Comment: Can you please try to use `include` instead of `helper` in your `ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs` module?

Comment: What about to create `helper_method :breadcrumbs` in `ApplicationController` and  put it under `protected`?

Comment: @heena-hussain, `include` can't help in this situation. Because `include` will make module code available from Controller. `helper` is making code available from View. It's not same, regrettably.

Comment: @sergey-kishenin, :helper_method is not a solution in this case. Because :helper_method is executing in controller context, not in helper/view context how it's doing method of a helper.

Comment: @redeye ok...then how about defining `BreadcrumbsHelper` module inside the 'ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs` module?

Comment: @HeenaHussain, than `helper BreadcrumbsHelper` still generate `undefined method 'helper'`

Comment: @redeye why do not you try to put your `BreadcrumbsHelper` method in `application_helper.rb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found how to connect helper to controller module:

```
module ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs     
  included { helper :breadcrumbs }

  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ApplicationController` would be inheriting `ActionController::Base`, that's why `ApplicationController` gets helper method inherited. 
Now the module `'ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs'`, you are using, doesn't have 'helper' method. So you will have to include helper module in `'ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs'` module to access helper's methods.

Try code given below:

```
module BreadcrumbsHelper
  def breadcrumbs_cache_wrap(key, options, &block)
    ...
  end
end

module ApplicationController::Breadcrumbs
  include BreadcrumbsHelper  
  def default_breadcrumbs
  ...
end
```

Comment: `ApplicationController` already inherited from `ActionController::Base`. I updated the question. Thank you for your attentiveness.
`include` can't help in this situation. Because `include` will make module code available from Controller. `helper` is making code available from View. It's not same, regrettably.

Comment: Can you specify what exactly you want to do? I mean what kind of code you want to access in controller